# Contains function for LPCTSTR

Tags: c++, c, contains

I have a code like:

```
int contains(LPCTSTR name)
{
   char * data = "test.txt";
}
```

How can i check whether `name` contains 'data'? Thanks!

Comment: If an `LPCTSTR` is some kind of `char*` (`const` qualified or not), `strstr` is what you want. If it's some kind of `wchar_t*`, you need to convert `data` first.

Comment: @DanielFischer LPCTSTR will be a char* in windows if the program has been compiled with multibyte support.  If it has been compiled with Unicode support then it'll be a wchar_t*.

Comment: @Benj And that is the question, Unicode or not?

Comment: You want to find if data is substring in name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a function called [`strstr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9da80kz%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) that is used to check for if a string contains another string. However, since you are using `LPCTSTR` you should note that it can be different depending on your project settings. If you read more in the linked manual page you will see it mention `_tcsstr` which is a macro that will expand to the correct function.

If you use C++ `std::string` instead, there is the [`find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) method.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using Windows and `TCHAR`, a more idiomatic solution would be:

```
BOOL contains(LPCTSTR name) {
    return _tcsstr(name, _T("data"));
}
```

Unless your `data` is deliberately a `char *`, in which case the answer changes.

Answer (score 2):

Unicode or not Unicode, you can use the [Shell Lightweight Utility String Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759983%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
int contains(LPTSTR name)
{
    LPTSTR data = _T("test.txt");
    if(StrStrI(name, data) != NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You'll need to include `shlwapi.h` and link `shlwapi.lib`.

Also note the `StrStrI` is case insensitive, to use case-sensitive, it's just `StrStr`.

Comment: According to [`StrStrI` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773439(v=vs.85).aspx), the **second** parameter of `StrStrI` is "_A pointer to the substring to search for_", so the it should be `data` (not `name`) in your sample code. Moreover, unfortunately, the first parameter of `StrStrI` is a **non-const** string, which doesn't respect the const-correctness on `name` (which is `LPCTSTR`, i.e. `const TCHAR*`).

Comment: That's right, but you know that was a typo. About the const thing, just need to change the parameter... which now is more generic.

Comment: OK for the typo. But I don't like removing the const correctness on the input parameter. Semantically, the `contains()` function should _not_ alter the string being searched.

Comment: More like a problem with the API, because `StrStrI` probably doesn't alter anything on the string.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `StrStrI` API, but if it doesn't change the input string being searched, you may want to still pass a `const TCHAR*` to `contains()`, and then `const_cast<TCHAR*>` to `StrStrI`.

Answer (score 1):

Others suggested C approaches; since you used the tag "c++", you may want to use that language and its features like `bool` return type, or string classes.

Moreover, since you are writing code for Windows (I read the `LPCTSTR name` parameter), you may want to use Windows specific convenient classes like `CString`.

In this case, you can just use [`CString::Find()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hz2099kw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), or wrap it in a function like this (that should compile in both ANSI/MBCS and Unicode builds):

```
bool ContainsSomeText(const CString& name)
{
    const TCHAR* data = _T("test.txt");
    return (name.Find(data) >= 0);
}
```

Moreover, if you want a *case insensitive* comparison, you may want to call [`CString::MakeLower()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/eyxcxazf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) on the input string (and in this case pass by value because you are modifying the copy):

```
bool ContainsSomeText(CString name)
{
    const TCHAR* data = _T("test.txt"); // lower-case
    return (name.MakeLower().Find(data) >= 0);
}
```

Comment: @FlávioToribio: Yes, also the parentheses `(...)` for the boolean expression for `return` are, but I think it's a matter of personal programming preference.

Comment: That's true. Same thing with my code. I could have used just a `return` with no `if`... but as I don't know the semantics of the function the OP wants, I'd probably do something more generic so that the OP can put more instructions and other stuff when the substring is found.